# Javafx format returns -0.00

Tags: properties, binding, javafx-8, string-formatting

I'm making a program where you can make a graph. You can drag the points around inside an AnchorPane. I use a GridPane for the layout of my Cartesian Coordinate system. So you can't drag the points out of the GridPane bounds. The relative x and y coordinate is shown (so value between 0 and 1). If I drag the point to the place where y=0 then it shows -0.00 for some strange reason. The other doubles are correct, it's only that one. Is there any possibility to remove that "-" or are there other options to bind this?

My bindings:

```
xCoord.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%,.2f", last.xProperty()));
yCoord.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%,.2f", last.yProperty()));
```

Comment: `-0d` and `+0d` are encoded in different ways in memory. Depending on the way you determine the values this could yield `+0d` or `-0d`...

Comment: What about instead of doing it with the above code you just implement a new StringBinding() ? You can specify the bind properties and inside the computeValue() method you can perform your calculation/evaluation of the string and return the correct format.

Comment: @fabian And is it possible to avoid/change this?

Comment: @JKostikiadis ok that worked. Thnx